# What is the "true" cost to send a freighter (spaceX or SoyuZ) to the ISS?

Tags: spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft

What is the real cost (all costs) in to send a freight craft  to ISS?  Which launch system is the most cost effective?

Comment: [This link](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/what-is-the-current-cost-per-pound-to-send-something-into-leo) gives an estimate per pound into low earth orbit, which depends on the actual rocket being used.  There are, of course, lots of overhead costs which I don't think are accounted for here.

Comment: All costs? Do you include just the incremental cost of building and launching another vehicle, or do you amortize development costs in there?  What about fixed costs associated with the army of personnel necessary to maintain a capability to launch?  The accounting on this is quite a bit trickier than you might suspect.

Comment: And the paperwork for any NASA job..

Comment: A really interesting question, but unanswerable - at best opinion based as to what constitutes a cost, particularly with shared and reused infrastructure

Comment: To clarify my question:  For this exercise imagine that a complete package complete is brought ready for mating with the spacecraft by the contractor.

Comment: Once successfully launched and in orbit the contractor will take control.

Comment: You should edit the question to list all costs you want and how you want them to be taken into account (amortizement, insurance, (partial) launch failure, bank reimboursment, dollar conversion for suppliers not payingnin dollar,...) It is a lot easier to provide the marginal cost of a successful launch than including all costs influing more or less directly the success of this launch.

Comment: Let me ask this a different way:

Comment: What is the cost for each launch of a soyuz to ISS (or a SpaceX resupply shuttle).  There must be a cost/launch

Comment: As a couple of people have pointed out, you should edit your question rather than putting "clarifications" in comments.  Anybody just breezing through won't see your comments, and will only see the incomplete question.

Answer (score 2):

The linked question on launch [cost per pound](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/what-is-the-current-cost-per-pound-to-send-something-into-leo) is a good starting point. Multiply this with a rocket's maximum payload and you have the true cost of one launch. This is what you'd pay to the launch provider to have your payload launched to LEO. The launch provider uses this to pay for building the rocket, transporting it to the launch site, launch services etc.

Launching to the ISS is more complicated. SpaceX advertises the launch price for a [Falcon 9](http://www.spacex.com/about/capabilities) at $62M. The NASA contract with SpaceX for ISS supply runs was more expensive at ~90M/launch, because NASA wanted extra certification work, and because the launch now includes a Dragon capsule.

For manned Soyuz launches to the ISS, [NASA paid \$70 million per seat in 2013](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/what-is-the-flyaway-cost-of-a-soyuz-and-proton-rocket). This seems to include a certain amount of price gouging and/or subsidies, because you can buy a generic Soyuz launch [for in the region of $60M](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/what-is-the-flyaway-cost-of-a-soyuz-and-proton-rocket).

Launch costs have always been difficult to calculate. SpaceX publishing them on their website has made it a bit easier, but I don't see Roscosmos putting the sticker price for a Soyuz on their site quite yet.